# Second timestamp column has an invalid default value

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp, default

If i execute my sql create table statement i get an errormessage that says:

> Invalid default value for 'end'

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `monkeybutler`.`Setuptimeslot` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `begin` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  `end` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

If I change the statement and comment out the "end"-column it works, but as soon as i try to create 2 columns of type TIMESTAMP it doesnt work anymore. How can I insert both columns without getting an error?

(This is the complete Create Table Statement and my mysql Version is 5.6.19)

Comment: The feature with more than one automatic timestamp columns was added with MySQL 5.6.5, I cite: **As of MySQL 5.6.5, TIMESTAMP and DATETIME columns can be automatically initializated and updated to the current date and time (that is, the current timestamp). Before 5.6.5, this is true only for TIMESTAMP, and for at most one TIMESTAMP column per table.** Please check with `SELECT VERSION()` which one you're using.

Comment: mysql> select version(); says I got: 5.6.19

Comment: Please post your complete create table statement. Your current one hasn't got any DEFAULT clauses, see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3e339

Comment: this is the curious thing about the error: this IS the complete create Statement

Comment: Then I can't reproduce such an error.